# Disabling Cartthrob via database - How to?

Tags: cartthrob, add-on, database

I have large scale website with cart throb added version 2.00xx. I have updated the EE from 2.1.3 to the latest 2.8.1 and I've got a lot of errors, but at least I had cp available. Under extensions section I had list of extensions - some of them was disabled - including Cartthrob pro. Since I enabled it, I completely lost the CP. Now it shows blank page. 
I'll really appreciate somebody to give me a tip how can I disable this extension via my sql admin by directly changing a record in the database?

Comment: I've set in table exp_extensions all fields carthrob_xxx_xx to "n"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporarily disable ALL addons by adding this to your config file:

```
$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';
```

This should allow you to access the Control Panel and then attempt to delete Cartthrob from there (if you're sure you don't want to delete all your sales data!). If that fails then look in the `exp_modules` and `exp_extensions` tables in the database and delete any and all entries for Cartthrob in there (as Cartthrob comprises of both a Module and an Extension). This will effectively delete Cartthrob and you should be able to load up your Control Panel and allow all other extensions in your config.php file again.

The `exp_cartthrob_x` tables will still remain in the database but you can delete these if you're absolutely sure you don't want any of your ecommerce data.